# Can we re-open the drink blood / eat flesh question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

This question, [What did Jesus mean when He said we must “eat His flesh and drink His blood”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/what-did-jesus-mean-when-he-said-we-must-eat-his-flesh-and-drink-his-blood) was closed by (moderator) Richard after he added this comment, *"Please provide a doctrinal stance in order to facilitate interpretation."*

I *think* I'm right in saying that this was at a time where *"doctrinal stance"* was in the ascendance here, as we were trying to work out more broadly what was on and off topic.

Anyway, I came across this today as I was just about to ask *exactly this question!*

This was after I have recently asked two other *"Why Jesus"* questions:

- [Why did Jesus tell His disciples to buy a sword?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7121/why-did-jesus-tell-his-disciples-to-buy-a-sword)
- [Why does Jesus say “you will be put to death” and yet “not a hair of your head will perish”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/why-does-jesus-say-you-will-be-put-to-death-and-yet-not-a-hair-of-your-head-w)

My point here is that currently we are being inconsistent. Either open them all (my preference) or close them all.

Comment: @Richard - "at-ing" you so that you can weigh in if you choose.

Comment: All three of these questions strictly ask for an interpretation of the relevant passage and none of them are particularly "Christian".  As such, they all would fit better on the Biblical Hermeneutics site, in my opinion.  In fact, the question in question got some good answers when it was asked there.  So I'm curious what would be gained by having the John 6 question reopened here?

Comment: @JonEricson: you've reminded me, I need to ask another question to get clarity on what goes where... But I've been reluctant to ask this so far because I'll need to research what's been discussed so far, first.

Comment: @Wikis Richard has stepped down from his moderator duties here so contacting him is not likely to do much.

Comment: @waxeagle - OK, thanks for the info. But he's still got a diamond!

Comment: @Wikis: For reasons unknown to us other mods, the StackExchange team has not seen fit to remove Richard's diamond. Thus, he is merely an inactive mod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that its probably ok given the current state of our site (obviously the rules are still in flux). Questions like it has been asked and done well around here.

I'll reopen.